# Monitoring dmesg output

Tags: linux, monitoring, log-files, dmesg

I find that when something goes wrong at a low level on one of my linux servers, I can see messages about it in the **kernel ring buffer**.  These can be viewed from the command line using the **dmesg** command.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to get my servers to **email me whenever something is added** to the kernel ring buffer?

Right now I have a script that runs every hour, makes a copy of the output of dmesg and runs a **diff** against the file from the previous hour.  Unfortunately this doesn't work so well, because as lines are appended to the end of the dmesg output, other lines are truncated from the beginning.  Also, if I have alot of the same message, it just stops notifying me altogether.

- Is there a better way of doing this?
- Does anyone else think it is important to see these messages when they happen?

*added*

- is the information reported by the **dmesg** command the same as that in one of the logfiles?  (If so, then the solution is easier than I thought)

Comment: I think whether and which log files match dmesg is system dependent. You can configure kern.* messages to go to a file or files of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will send any new entries to /var/log/kern.log to the root user.
Putting it in **/etc/cron.hourly** will send an email every hour, but only if there are new kernel messages.

```
#!/bin/bash

MAILTO=root
LOG=/var/log/kern.log

OFFSET_FILE=$0.offset
if [ ! -f $OFFSET_FILE ]; then echo 0 > $OFFSET_FILE; fi
OFFSET=`cat $OFFSET_FILE`
FILESIZE=`cat $LOG|wc -c`

# Check if log has been rotated
if [ "$OFFSET" -gt "$FILESIZE" ]; then
  OFFSET=0
  echo 0 > $OFFSET_FILE
fi
if [ "$FILESIZE" -gt "$OFFSET" ]; then
  tail -c+$OFFSET $LOG|sed "s/^/  /"|mail $MAILTO -s "new kernel alerts"
  echo $FILESIZE > $OFFSET_FILE
fi
```

Comment: $OFFSET and $FILESIZE are in terms of characters (wc -c), but then the tail command is done in terms of lines (-n). They need to match. I would make it wc -l, but tail -c makes it where the outputs don't overlap by one line so that might be preferred.

Comment: Good catch Dennis, I will add -c to the script above.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools designed to gather this information and report it regularly.

I find the Lire tool (from the [LogReport](http://www.logreport.org/) system) to be a good reporting tool, but you may also be interested in [Logcheck](http://logcheck.org/) and [Logwatch](http://www.logwatch.org/). All are [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and can be installed directly from most major GNU/Linux package repositories.

Comment: I think the asker wanted something that happened a little more often, but I don't really think there is anything. I use logcheck and have voted +1

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and dirty solution. You may get **lots** of mail. I'd advise adding some `grep` and/or `grep -v` commands. Of course you can use this technique for other log files, too. Add this command in your `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` or your system's equivalent (after having tested it from the command line).

```
sudo tail -F /var/log/messages | while read line ; do echo "$line"|mail -s Subject recipient; done &
```

**edit**: changed to capital F to make tail follow the file by name to be able to handle log rotation.

Comment: Instead of tailing /var/log/messages (which may get log-entries from other syslog facilities) you could configure syslogd to log kern.* to another file and tail that. In addition, be mindful of logrotate which probably will break this when it does it's thing.

Comment: I edited my answer to handle the case of log rotation. Your suggestion regarding kern.* messages is a good one. I'd keep them going to /var/log/messages, too, though (just to be clear).

Comment: On my system (Debian), the output of "dmesg" is different from /var/log/messages.

Comment: ... It MAY be the same as /var/log/kern.log though - can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @Brent - This Fedora 11 system doesn't have kern.log, but my Ubuntu desktop does.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice utility called cronolog(1) which reads a stream and splits it based on a date template. Example from one of my Apache config files:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog -z0 /var/log/apache2/example.org/%Y/%Y-%m-%dZ.access_log" combined
```

This will split all Apache logs into a example.org/yyyy/yy-mm-ddZ.access_log format which makes life generally easier.

Now, how this can be used in your situation: Start a process which logs everything that happens in /var/log/messages :

```
tail -F /var/log/messages | cronolog -z0 /var/log/mylog/dmesg/%Y-%m-%d_%H.log &
```

This will split the output into files with the filename format

```
/var/log/mylog/dmesg/yyyy-mm-dd_hh.log
```

Every two minutes past the hour, run a script from cron that checks if there's generated a logfile the last hour. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is executed every XX:02 from cron

LOGDIR=/var/log/mylog/dmesg
# Get date string five minutes ago
LOGDATE=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d_%H" -d "5 min ago")

if [ -e $LOGDIR/$LOGDATE.log ]; then
    mail -s "dmesg log for $LOGDATE" my@mail.com <$LOGDIR/$LOGDATE.log
fi
```

If no file is found, no mail is sent. With this system, you'll also have backups of your log in the $LOGDIR directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a kern.log and would like to create and keep one, edit /etc/syslog.conf and add the following

`kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log`

Try 'man 5 syslog.conf' if you want more help on configuring syslogd.

Also swatch (http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/) is another tool that can easily be configured to watch log files.

Answer (score 0):

StackKrish is on the right track but still doesn't send email. To do that you could use something like syslog-ng which allows logging to commands to a program with the the program() destination. If you don't want to do that you can get regular syslogd to log to a named pipe/fifo which then can be hooked up to a simple script that would send out the email.